# Fast method to cycle through multiple lists of tuples to find max of each tuple list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples, vectorization

I have tens of thousands of lists of tuples, where each tuple within a list consists of an `(int, float)` pair. I want to be able to cycle through all the lists of tuples to find the `(int, float)` pair where the `float` is the maximum value of the float in the list of tuples. Consider several lists of tuples:

```
[
[(0, 0.3792), (3, 0.5796)],
[0, 0.9365), (1, 0.0512), (18, 0.0123),
[(13, 0.8642)],
[(0, 0.6249), (1, 0.01), (2, 0.01), (3, 0.01), (4, 0.01), (5, 0.01)]
]
```

For each list of tuples, I want to find the pair where the second number is maximized (e.g., for the first list, I want `(3, 0.5796)`; for the 4th item, `(0, 0.6249)` should be returned). My current approach is to turn the tuples into numpy arrays and then find argmax and max:

```
def get_max(doc: List[Tuple[int, float]]) -> Tuple[int, float]:
            
   topic_prob_array = np.array(doc, dtype=np.dtype('int,float'))
   return topic_prob_array['f0'][np.argmax(topic_prob_array['f1'])], np.max(topic_prob_array['f1'])
```

I was hoping to turn this into a numpy vectorized function (via `vec_func = np.vectorized(get_max, otypes=[int,float])` or numpy ufunc (via `vec_func = np.fromfunc(get_max, nin=1, nout=1)`. I not sure if I am formatting the input and output correctly. My reasoning is that I am sending in a single list of tuples and return a single tuple, hence `nin=1, nout=1`. However, I have not been able to successfully get a vectorized version of this to run.

I also tried a solution without relying on `numpy`:

```
def get_max(doc: List[Tuple[int, float]]) -> Tuple[int, float]:

   ids, probabilities = zip(*doc)
   return ids[np.argmax(probabilities)], np.max(probabilities)
```

Both take about the same amount of time to run. For my list of about 80k, this takes about 1 minute, 10 seconds for both implementations. I'd really like to get this down if it's possible.

Comment: Are you looking for a numpy answer?

Comment: `np.vectorize`, despite the name, does not "vectorize", in the sense of making a fast compiled function.  `np.frompyfunc` is faster than `np.vectorize`, but still no faster than a simple list comprehension.  In addition, they pass "scalar" values to the function.  You want to pass a sublist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimized non-`numpy` solution to this is:

```
from operator import itemgetter

get1 = itemgetter(1)

all_lists = [...]  # Whatever your actual list of list of tuples comes from

all_maxes = [max(lst, key=get1) for lst in all_lists]
```

`numpy` isn't likely to gain you much, since the work done is relatively cheap, and if you're only converting to `numpy` arrays for a single operation, the scope of benefit is smaller.

Comment: Thanks for this. I should've specified that non-`numpy` solutions are totally fine. I was just thinking that maybe some of this could be helped with `numpy.vectorize`. This solution is faster than the one I was implementing by about 10-15 seconds, which helps. I was really just hoping to get the processing down quite a bit more, but it seems that I'm limited by the data structure. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use `numpy` for this? We can take a functional approach and `map` the `max` function with a custom `key` across the whole data set.

```
from functools import partial
from operator import itemgetter

snd = itemgetter(1)
p = partial(max, key=snd)
list(map(p, data))
>>> [(3, 0.5796), (0, 0.9365), (13, 0.8642), (0, 0.6249)]
```

Then a quick timing across 80K random tuples from your original dataset.

```
from random import choice

result = []
for _ in range(80_000):
    result.append(choice(data))

%timeit list(map(p, result))
42.2 ms ± 686 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I think you forgot to define `snd` here. Guessing you meant the same basic definition I used, given the `itemgetter` import?

Comment: yes good catch, just updated it, same approach just more of a _functional_ twist

Comment: Well, listcomps are just as much a functional construct as `map`. That said, your solution is likely to be faster if the input is large enough (`map` where the mapping function can push all the work to the C layer is usually faster than a listcomp that has to run the bytecode for the loop inside the listcomp).

Comment: Thanks for this answer; I'd never heard of `partial` before, but I'm probably gonna start using it more often. Against my dataset (consisting of 83,170 documents, some with as many as 20 tuples in the lists), this code yielded `1min 2s ± 335 ms per loop`, while @ShadowRanger code yielded `1min 2s ± 303 ms per loop`. Makes sense since the code was similar. My original non-`numpy` code was clocking at `1min 11s ± 640 ms per loop`. So a good improvement, but I think I'm limited by the data structure.

Comment: @CopyOfA: Thanks for the timings; would you mind saying which version of Python you're using? I'm assuming 3.8+; your inputs are large enough that in the past, I'd have expected `map` to win (by virtue of avoiding repeated lookups for builtins like `max`, and avoiding bytecode interpreter overhead per item), but the `LOAD_GLOBAL` "per opcode cache" [introduced in 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#optimizations) might mean that load overhead for built-ins is lower than the wrapping overhead from `partial` now, enough to make up for the bytecode interpreter overhead.

Comment: Yeah, I'm in Python 3.8.8. I think, technically, the list of lists of tuples is a generator (its type is `gensim.interfaces.TransformedCorpus`), so I'm not sure if that also plays a role in the performance.

Comment: EDIT: I was wrong about it being a generator. It appears to behave like a list (i.e., I can call `lst[0]`, `lst[1]`, etc. and get outputs).

Answer (score 1):

Like @gold_cy mentioned, I'm not sure if you're looking for a `numpy` answer. A non-`numpy` answer could be:

```py
list_tuple = [
    [(0, 0.3792), (3, 0.5796)],
    [(0, 0.9365), (1, 0.0512), (18, 0.0123)],
    [(13, 0.8642)],
    [(0, 0.6249), (1, 0.01), (2, 0.01), (3, 0.01), (4, 0.01), (5, 0.01)]
]

[sorted(tup, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True).pop(0) for tup in list_tuple]
```

```
>>> [(3, 0.5796), (0, 0.9365), (13, 0.8642), (0, 0.6249)]
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `sorted` here; that involves `O(n log n)` sorting work and a bunch of temporary `list`s when a `key`-ed `max` would do `O(n)` work and involve no temporary `list`s.

Comment: @ShadowRanger hmm interesting - I never saw your kind of answer before. I'll check it out and learn something new.

Comment: It's a common oversight I've found; lots of people leap for `sorted` (which is awesome for things that actually require sorting the whole or a large portion of the input) when `max`/`min` would do the work (or when they need more than one `max`/`min`, but only a small portion of the input, `heapq.nlargest`/`heapq.nsmallest`). Your answer isn't terrible, it's just doing a little unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [462]: alist
Out[462]: 
[[(0, 0.3792), (3, 0.5796)],
 [(0, 0.9365), (1, 0.0512), (18, 0.0123)],
 [(13, 0.8642)],
 [(0, 0.6249), (1, 0.01), (2, 0.01), (3, 0.01), (4, 0.01), (5, 0.01)]]
In [463]: blist = alist*10000    # bigger test list
```

Playing around with alternatives, I found this "brute force" function is fastest (though not by much):

```
def get_max3(doc):
    m = doc[0]
    for i in doc[1:]:
        if i[1]>m[1]: m=i
    return m
```

For the small list, the list comprehension is slightly faster, for the big list, the map version has the edge - but not by much.

```
In [465]: [get_max3(i) for i in alist]
Out[465]: [(3, 0.5796), (0, 0.9365), (13, 0.8642), (0, 0.6249)]

In [466]: timeit [get_max3(i) for i in alist]
1.9 µs ± 51.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [467]: timeit list(map(get_max3,blist))
15 ms ± 7.77 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Versions using `numpy` are all much slower; it takes time to convert the list of tuples into a numpy array (even structured array).

Comment: Yeah, I agree about `numpy`, after timing the solutions, `numpy` seems to take longer and certainly the conversion plays a role in that. And there's not much to be gained in that conversion, so it's all loss. Thanks for the help!